# Implementing push/pop in a linked list (C++)

Tags: c++, stack, linked-list, implementation

I'm trying to incorporate push/pop into a linked list and I can't seem to get it to work. When I run my test function, I set my linked list to zero and I try to push on values but the list keeps getting returned with no values in it.  Could anyone possibly tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (top == NULL){
      current = top;
      current->next = NULL; //NULL->next : will cause segfault
  }
```

if top is NULL, you set `current = top` [which is NULL], and then you access `current->next`, which will cause a segfault, you are trying to access NULL..

**EDIT**: follow up to comments:

your if statement seems redundant, you should probably only need to set: `current->next = head;` and `head = current;` [in addition to the current allocation]

Comment: I changed it around from top=current but I'm still not getting returned anything.

Comment: @BleuCheese: The problem is that you're changing only the local variable `top` when you would need to be changing the global variable `head` -- otherwise, your changes won't "survive" beyond the end of the function.

Comment: your if statement seems redundant, you should probably only need to set: `current->next = head;` and `head = current;`

Comment: I'm so thankful that you guys pointed this out.  I've been having so much trouble with pointers and stuff lately but you guys cleared so much up.  My code works perfect now.  Thank you so much. :)))))

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
 if (top == NULL){
      current = top;
      current->next = NULL;
 }
```

you want

```
 if (top == NULL){
      top = current;
      current->next = NULL;
 }
```

And of course, after this, you have to make sure that you actually set `head` to `top` again.

Now that you've made this change, it should be clear that both cases do the same thing -- so no case distinction is actually necessary. So the function can be simplified to

```
void push(Data * newPushData){
    LinkNode * current = new LinkNode(newPushData);
    current->next = head;
    head = current;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `top` variable is local variable for `push(...)` function. You can use `head` instead, and I'd rather modify the `if` statement.

I think that function should look like this:

```
void push(Data * newPushData){
    LinkNode * current = new LinkNode(newPushData);
    if (head != NULL){
        current->next = head;
        head = current;
    }
    else{
        head = current;
        current->next = NULL; // if you haven't done it in LinkNode constructor
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void push(Data * newPushData)
{
    if( head != NULL )
    {
        LinkNode current = new LinkNode(newPushData);
        current->next = head;
        head = current;
    }
    else
    {
        head = new LinkNode(newPushData);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you please specify the attributes of the linked list class ?  [ is there slightly chance you are doing something wrong]

Instead of you , I'd do :

```
void push(Data * newPushData){
if (head   == NULL) 
    head->data = newPushData
    tail = head ; 

else // regular situation 
     { 
     Node  * node  = new Node() ; 
     tail->next = node; 
     node->data  = newPushData; 
     node->next  = NULL ;
     tail  = node ; 
   }
```

}

In a linked list you have got to maintain the head pointer point on the head  of the list ,  maintain that the tail pointer is point on the tail of the list , 
You must take care of the 2 cases of enlarging the list.
the best way for learning is to illustrate an  insertion on a blank  linked list.

Take care
S

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

```
void push(data * newpushdata){
    if(head !=null){
        linkednode current = new linkednode(newpushdata);
        current->next = head;
        head = current;
    }
    else {
       head = new linkednode(newpushdata);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

that is my working solution for a Stack containing int elements, but maybe it's better to create a void pushStack using Stack **S instead of Stack *S.

in pop(Stack **S) i created a sentinel, so if the stack is empty -1 is returned.:

```
typedef struct StackT {

    int val;
    struct StackT *next;

} Stack;

int isStackEmpty (Stack *S) {

    if (S == NULL)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}


int *pop(Stack **S) {
    Stack *tmp = *S;
    int i = -1;
    if (isStackEmpty(tmp) == 0) {
        i = tmp->val;
        *S = tmp->next;
    }
    return i;
}

Stack *pushStack (Stack *S, int x) {

    Stack *node = (Stack *) malloc (sizeof (Stack));
    node->val = x;
    node->next = S;

    return node;
}
```

you can call pop and stack easly:

```
    Stack *S = NULL;
    int x = somevalue;
    int y;
    S = pushStack(S, x);
    y = pop(&S);
```